# Adding time to current time give error of 1 minute (Kotlin / Java)

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, kotlin

When I add new time to calendar instance it gives me the error of 1 minute.

I get time from API response in this format

`"PredictedArrivalDateTime": "/Date(1549309800000+1100)/"`

> this is just a dummy date from my API response

Then I use `dateFromDotNetDate(dotNetDate: String)` function to get difference in minutes.

After that, I want to add this minutes to the current time (eg: 12:30 ) and get new time which I am doing using the following function
`calculateNextTime(diffInMillies: Long)`

Following is my DateTimeUtil util code

```
class DateTimeUtil {

    //Holds difference time difference in Minuets
    var mDifferenceMin: String? = null

    //HoldsETA of next Tram
    var mNextTime: String? = null

    //Convert .NET Date to Date
    fun dateFromDotNetDate(dotNetDate: String) {
        val startIndex = dotNetDate.indexOf("(") + 1
        val endIndex = dotNetDate.indexOf("+")
        val date = dotNetDate.substring(startIndex, endIndex)

        val unixTime = java.lang.Long.parseLong(date)
        val diffInMinutes = calculateDifference(Date(), unixTime)

        mDifferenceMin = diffInMinutes
        //----------------
        if (diffInMinutes == "0") {
            mDifferenceMin = "Now"
        } else
            mDifferenceMin = diffInMinutes
    }

    private fun calculateDifference(d1: Date, d2: Long): String? {
        val diffInMillies = Math.abs(d2 - d1.time)
        val diff = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

        calculateNextTime(diffInMillies)
        //----------------------
        return diff.toString()
    }

    private fun calculateNextTime(diffInMillies: Long) {
        //calculate next time
        val df = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.getDefault())
        val now = Calendar.getInstance()
        now.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, diffInMillies.toInt())
        val teenMinutesFromNow = df.format(now.time)
        val nextTime = teenMinutesFromNow

        mNextTime = nextTime
    }
}
```

[image: See Attached screensot]

The current time is 12:41 in device, next ETA is 18 min so if i add (12:41 + 18 min = 12:59) but its showing 1:00

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the `java.time` API? It might yield more accurate results.

Comment: it requires minimum API 26 which i cant do right now, Is there any way its guffing up in time conversions and date time to long conversions?

Comment: @AkshayKatariya You might as well try the ThreeTen Backport.

Comment: `1549309800000` is `2019-02-04T19:50:00Z`. Applying offset `1100` yields `2019-02-05T06:50+11:00` or `2019-02-04T08:50-11:00`. None of these values are anywhere close to `12:41`, so how is any of that related to 18 minutes difference? Please edit question and provide [**Minimal**, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Andreas I edited my question it was just a dummy date for reference which I had from my API response

Comment: Agreeing with @Slaw and @MCEmperor: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, the terrible date-time classes `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. For earlier Android (<26) see [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

I just change one line and magic happened

from

```
now.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, diffInMillies.toInt())
```

to

```
now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, diffInMin.toInt())
```

As I thought the MILLISECOND calculation was introducing bugs in my function
when I calculated using Minutes it's working fine